# How to create a distribution Bar Plot in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stackedbarseries

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Player_id  Draft_Year  Rnd  Pick   Tm  ... Vert Leap (in) Broad Jump (in)  Shuttle  3Cone  60Yd Shuttle
0   2015Jameis Winston        2015    1     1  TAM  ...           28.5           103.0     4.36   7.16           NaN
1   2015Marcus Mariota        2015    1     2  TEN  ...           36.0           121.0     4.11   6.87           NaN
2     2015Dante Fowler        2015    1     3  JAX  ...           32.5           112.0     4.32   7.40         11.89
3     2015Amari Cooper        2015    1     4  OAK  ...           33.0           120.0     3.98   6.71           NaN
4  2015Brandon Scherff        2015    1     5  WAS  ...            NaN             NaN      NaN    NaN           NaN
```

I'm trying to create a stacked bar plot that will show the distribution of 40 times, color coded by position. The end result will look something like this:
[Distributuion Bar Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psP8e.png)

I've tried using stacked bar graphs with matplotlib but keep getting an error message. Here is my code:

```
x = df['40 Yard']
y1 = df['Position Standard'][0]
y2 = df['Position Standard'][1]
y3 = df['Position Standard'][2]
plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))

# stack bars
plt.bar(x, y1, label='y1')
plt.bar(x, y2 ,bottom=y1,label='y2')
plt.bar(x, y3 ,bottom=y1+y2,label='y3')

# memo of sample number
snum = y1+y2+y3

# normalization
y1 = y1/snum*100.
y2 = y2/snum*100.
y3 = y3/snum*100.

# add text annotation corresponding to the percentage of each data.
for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y1/2, y1):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "%.1f"%yval, ha="center", va="center")
for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y1+y2/2, y2):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "%.1f"%yval, ha="center", va="center")
for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y1+y2+y3/2, y3):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "%.1f"%yval, ha="center", va="center")
# add text annotation corresponding to the "total" value of each bar
for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y1+y2+y3, snum):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "N=%d"%yval, ha="center", va="bottom")

plt.ylim(0,110)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01,0.5), loc='center left')

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-250-521232e1cbd6> in <module>
      7 # stack bars
      8 plt.bar(x, y1, label='y1')
----> 9 plt.bar(x, y2 ,bottom=y1,label='y2')
     10 plt.bar(x, y3 ,bottom=y1+y2,label='y3')
     11 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in bar(x, height, width, bottom, align, data, **kwargs)
   2407     return gca().bar(
   2408         x, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, align=align,
-> 2409         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2410 
   2411 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1563     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1564         if data is None:
-> 1565             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1566 
   1567         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)
   2394                 edgecolor=e,
   2395                 linewidth=lw,
-> 2396                 label='_nolegend_',
   2397                 )
   2398             r.update(kwargs)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in __init__(self, xy, width, height, angle, **kwargs)
    725         """
    726 
--> 727         Patch.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    728 
    729         self._x0 = xy[0]

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in __init__(self, edgecolor, facecolor, color, linewidth, linestyle, antialiased, hatch, fill, capstyle, joinstyle, **kwargs)
     87         self.set_fill(fill)
     88         self.set_linestyle(linestyle)
---> 89         self.set_linewidth(linewidth)
     90         self.set_antialiased(antialiased)
     91         self.set_hatch(hatch)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py in set_linewidth(self, w)
    393                 w = mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth']
    394 
--> 395         self._linewidth = float(w)
    396         # scale the dash pattern by the linewidth
    397         offset, ls = self._us_dashes

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to probably convert your dataframe columns to integers

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html

Comment: Columns shown in the dataframe example have nothing to do with the code, please add `40 Yard` and `Position Standard`.